# Storing information on Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

My concern here is that I don't know if I have the right understanding on this which I need your help on to help clarify on. I've search through stack-overflow and couldn't find this information. I am just asking for theory re-clarification here.

The question is: I am working on an app where it retrieve information from Parse. The parse table contain name(String), animal(String), favorite(boolean). I am working on creating a Favorite section on the app where if user click on Favorite on the following information, it would set the following information favorite = true.

The concern here is, since I am using Parse, say, if the user tap on Bob(name), Dog, (animal), true(favorite). It will change the favorite from false to true. And I would then go to the Favorite section where it will read the whole database and find if favorite == true and display it.

Since it's parse which mean everyone receive the same information, say Person 1 tap favorite on Gurl(name), Cat(animal), true(favorite). Will Person 1 see information of Bob(name), Dog, (animal), true(favorite) which she didn't favorite but was favorite by different person? That's my only concern as I only wanted specific people seeing what they favorite.

How would you go about dealing this? I've read several information recommending Parse and this is my concern and several people recommending Core Data however, from my understanding, Core Data shouldnt contain a large information since I will be working on a large information on this project. Appreciate your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Will Person 1 see information of Bob(name), Dog, (animal), true(favorite) which she didn't favorite but was favorite by different person?**

In a nutshell: Yes.

If you want to have control about what data the app will show for each user, you have to use at least some user logic(can use `PFUser` provided by Parse out of the box) and maybe some ACL.

**The following modeling/logic is just a suggestion, I don't have the full knoledge about in what your trying to accomplish.**

1 - Have a class in your Parse database with `Name, Animal, Favorite, Pointer<PFUser>`

2 - When listing the favorites on the app, create a filter like
`query.whereKey("user", PFUser.current())`

3 - When the user taps to favorite something do

```
// If using PFSubclassing
let yourParseModel = MyModel()
yourParseModel.favorite = true
yourParseModel.user = PFUser.current()

// If NOT using PFSubclassing
let obj = PFObject(className: "YourClassName")
obj["favorite"] = true
obj["user"] = PFUser()
```

Comment: Thank you for the information!! That is really helpful, I totally missed out on the user part. However, I do have another question, what do you think about local database that are stored on the devices

Comment: I think local databases are essential when talking about cache or application specific cases. I have a project using Parse's local datastore and I don't recommend using it due to performance issues. In a class with ~1,5k registers, it took about 0.8s to perform a query with low complexity filters. Since Parse is very easy to use I'd recommend you to use it just to download/save data from/on the cloud but locally use something like Core Data or Realm. btw, last time I checked this performance issue was known and there was an issue on GitHub but I don't if they have worked on it.

Comment: Here's the issue about the performance with local datastore https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/32